# CasperJS loop doesn't evaluate properly, apparently just runs straight through

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, casperjs

I have the following code:

```
        function getLinks() {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.row-link');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('href');
        });
    }


    casper.start('http://somedomain.com/board/search/search/?p=' + pagee);

   // Get all the pages here! 
   casper.then(function(){
        while(pagenos = nextpagereg.exec(this.getHTML())) {;
              this.echo(pagenos);
              pages.push(pagenos);


        }
        this.echo(pages.length + ' PAGES FOUND');
        return pages;
    });


    casper.then(function() {
         pagee = 0;

        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');


        this.each(pages, function(self,page){
          pagee++;
          this.echo('WORKING ON PAGE' + pagee);
          self.thenOpen('http://somedomain.com/board/search/search/?p=' + pagee, function(self){
           this.each(links, function(self, link){

            self.thenOpen(link, function(self, a){

              title = this.getHTML('h2#job-title').trim();
              if(casper.exists('p#job-subtitle a')){
                company = this.getHTML('p#job-subtitle a');
              } else {
                title = "NA"; 
              }

              loc = this.getHTML('p#job-subtitle>strong');
              email = regex.exec(this.getHTML());
              this.echo("Title : " + title);
              this.echo("Company : " + company);
              this.echo("Location : " + loc);
              this.echo("Email : " + email);


              this.echo("************************************************************************************************************");


            });
            //this.echo(link);

         });

        });
        });

    });

    casper.run(function() {
        this.exit();
    });
```

The problems seems to be that it doesn't run through the pages in order, the outside loop just crashes through all the page links!

EDIT

To clarify this is the output, as you can see the loop shoots through all the page increments before its processed each page:

```
    http://somedomain.com/job-board/search/@/?p=2
    http://somedomain.com/job-board/search/search/?p=3
    http://somedomain.com/job-board/search/search/?p=4
    http://somedomain.com/job-board/search/search/?p=5
    http://somedomain.com/job-board/search/search/?p=6
    5 PAGES FOUND
    50 links found in page 1:
 LOOP START
    WORKING ON PAGE1
    WORKING ON PAGE2
    WORKING ON PAGE3
    WORKING ON PAGE4
    WORKING ON PAGE5
```

Comment: What is `nextpagereg`? Can you share the code?

Comment: Sure, it definately gets all of them its:
var nextpagereg = /http:\/\/somedomain.com\/job-board\/search\/\search\/\?p=[0-9]/g;

Comment: It looks like you need to scrape the links on each of the five pages, but you only do this once before you start iterating. You should move `links = this.evaluate(getLinks);` before the `each` in `self.thenOpen('http://somedomain.com/..."...`. Though, I don't think this solves your problem. Please add `echo` statements into every `each` and `thenOpen` block.

Comment: *slams head on desk* I HATE it when I do things like that i'd been messing with this for like 2 hours. What-an-idiot. Good catch though thanks!

Comment: Does this really solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't grabbing the new set of links after getting the next page, as I said what an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to scrape the links on each of the five pages, but you only do this once before you start iterating.

You should add

```
links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
```

into `self.thenOpen('http://somedomain.com/board/search/search/?p=' + pagee, ...` before the `each`.

A cleaner way would be to *move* the `getLinks` into `self.thenOpen` and exchange the top-most

```
this.each(pages, function(self,page){
    ...
});
```

with

```
for(var page = 0; page < pages.length; page++){
    ...
}
```